# Which countries refer to themselves by their shape?

Tags: factoids

The French refer to their country as *l'Hexagone*, as mainland France is [approximately hexagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hexagone.png). What other countries refer to themselves by the shape of their territory?

Comment: I've actually never heard that term used by any French person.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it solicits an open-ended list where every answer is equally correct, defeating the mechanics of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @JonCuster It is a common expression. Every French person will understand: https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagone_(France)

Comment: Just to forestall an erroneous answer that I nearly posted - the nation of Chile does not derive its name from being similar in shape to a chile pepper.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chile#Etymology) gives several proposed etymologies for the name of the country, all coming from indigenous terms, whereas the word "chile" for the fruit is of Nahuatl origin (now central Mexico), and the similarity is just a coincidence.

Comment: @choster Doesn't an answer need to provide a full list to be correct? We can vote on which list is most accurate.

Comment: relevant, but not an answer, hence the comment, is Mimal, the chef: https://laughingsquid.com/chef-with-fried-chicken-hidden-on-map-of-usa/

Comment: @bdsl All the answers thus far are lists of one. In the olden days, this might have been the kind of thing answered with a community wiki, but even then it's borderline. Travel.SE is not supposed to be SE's dumping ground for "interesting geographic or cultural trivia, because those things exist in a place I might travel to," although it is frequently treated as such.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about travel.

Answer (score 16):

Italy nicknamed lo Stivale (the Boot).

https://static.seekingalpha.com/uploads/2018/8/16/saupload_latest.png

Answer (score 8):

The **Finnish Maiden** (*Suomi-neito*) refers to the shape of Finland, which looks vaguely like a woman in a long dress with one hand raised:

[image]

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finnish_Maiden; the red bits represent territory lost to Russia after WW2.

Notably, the "arm" is known in Finnish as "The Arm" (*Käsivarsi*) and former capital Turku has the unfortunate designation of being Finland's butt (*Suomen perse*; it's even more rude in the original).

Comment: I would have placed the butt closer to Oulu, I don't see how Turku is any closer to being the butt than Helsinki is? They both seem closer to the feet for me

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how relevant it is, but Russia is self-referred as "one seventh of dry land" (*одна седьмая часть суши*).

Used to be "one sixth"(?) at the time of USSR. Wolfram Alpha says the real ratio is closer to one ninth.

Answer (score 2):

Mother India (Bharat Mata in Hindi) since the shape is like a lady standing draped in a saree (traditional Indian female attire) with her arms open. Check the map below.
[image]